# How can I call my function to make this program work to calculate grades?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int grade_calculation (int grade_input){
    if ( grade_input >= 100 && grade_input <= 90){
        cout << 'A';
    } else if (grade_input >= 89 && grade_input <= 80){
        cout << 'B';
    } else if (grade_input >= 79 && grade_input <= 70){
        cout << 'C';
    } else if (grade_input >= 69 && grade_input <= 60){
        cout << 'D';
    } else if (grade_input >= 59 && grade_input <= 0){
        cout << 'F';
    } else {
        cout << "NOT VALID.";
    }
}

int main()
{
    int score = 100;
    int grade_input;
    cout << "Enter a grade: ";
    cin >> grade_input;
    while (grade_input != score){
        cout << "Enter a new grade: ";
        cin >> grade_input;
        grade_calculation(grade_input);
        
    } cout << grade_input;
    return 0;
}
```

How can I properly use the while loop to ask the user for a letter and then output the corresponding grade?
Is there another way to call the function besides using "grade_calculation (grade_input)"?

Comment: Think `grade_input >= 100 && grade_input <= 90` through a bit more. Can a number be both greater than 100 and less than 90 at the same time?

Comment: Would recommend adopting `if(90 <= x && x < 100)` - keep the arrows pointing the same way, and visually put your variable in between the lower and upper limit - much clearer that way!

Answer (score 2):

```
if ( grade_input >= 100 && grade_input <= 90)
```

This means: *if the grade is above 100 and the grade is below 90*. There is no grade that satisfy this condition. You probably want:

```
if ( grade_input <= 100 && grade_input >= 90)
```

which is: *if grade is below or equal to 100 and grade is equal or above 90*.

And then, change all other conditions in a similar way.

Comment: I don't think this bug is what the asker is asking about. *How can I properly use the while loop to **ask the user for a letter** and then output the corresponding grade?*